# SQL looping through a table to count and group

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
 ID|list
  1|:A:B:C:
  2|:B:D:A:
  3|:C:A:D:
```

I want to count the number of each of A,B,C,D and group them as

```
A|3
B|2
C|2
D|2
```

I was thinking about iterating through the table and inserting values in to a temporary table from count statements like the following

```
select count(*) from table where list like %:A:%
```

It does look ugly.Is there a better way to do this?

(I am using sqlite from qt)

Comment: The best way would be to change the table structure. Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: @juergen Thanks for the reply.Number of values in each list is unknown .Sometimes there are 10, sometimes 0 like that.

Comment: So? What is your table for and what is in the list?

Comment: It is keeping movie data.The example is movie id and actors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never, never, never store multiple values in one column! A better DB design would be

```
movies table
----------
id
name
release_date
...


actors table
------------
id
first_name
last_name
birth_date
...


movie_cast table
----------------
movie_id
actor_id
```

You could then select all actors of a specific movie like this

```
select a.lastName, a.first_name
from actors a
join movie_cast c on c.actor_id = a.id
join movies m on c.movie_id = m.id
where m.name = 'Citizen Kane'
```

Or select all movies a specific actor stars in like this

```
select m.name
from actors a
join movie_cast c on c.actor_id = a.id
join movies m on c.movie_id = m.id
where a.lastName ='Wayne'
and a.first_name 'John'
```

Comment: @juergan-Still movie cast table will have variable number of columns?

Comment: if i have to allocate say 15 columns..many of them will be null for most of the movies.

Comment: No, only 2 columns. If a movie has 3 actors in it then you generate 3 **rows**. Example: `Movie_id = 1, Actors 5,6,7`: The 3 rows would be `(1,5),(1,6),(1,7)`

Comment: Does it affect the performance to have that many rows(in my case it will be around 30000)?.I haven't worked in SQL before..

Comment: No, not at all. Put those 2 columns in a single unique index. This will speed up things and you can easily have millions of records in that table.